# How to access the font programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, gdi+, plesk

I'm trying to access to a font programmatically, because i cant install fonts on the sharing hosting

I use this code

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim collection As New PrivateFontCollection()
    collection.AddFontFile(Server.MapPath("~\ShadowsIntoLight.ttf"))

    Dim image As New Bitmap(500, 500)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

    Dim RedBrush As New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
    Dim drawFont As New Font("Shadows Into Light", 36)

    g.DrawString("the lazy fox jumped over the brown log", drawFont, RedBrush, 0, 100)

    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/image.png")
    image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Png)
    g.Dispose()
    image.Dispose()

    Response.Write("<img src=""image.png""/>")

End Sub
```

but it always displays the Arial font.
How can I make it display the specific font

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not use CSS in the background?
Add the custom font to your solution in a 'Fonts folder' > add existing item to fonts folder in visual studio

Example: (Using a random font I downloaded)

```
@font-face{
font-family: myFont;
src: url(/Fonts/Belleza-Regular.ttf);
```

}

```
.MyClass{
color:green;
font-family: myFont;
 }
```

Then append this font anywhere within your code?

```
myControl.CssClass = "MyClass" etc..
```

Might be a slightly longer way than you wanted and would only work if you're appending to controls and such however might be a nice workaround.

**Edit:**

maybe something like this?
[Using custom TTF font for DrawString image rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523246/using-custom-ttf-font-for-drawstring-image-rendering)

Comment: I want to  access the font using GDI+ but not using CSS

Comment: Ah okay, maybe something like this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523246/using-custom-ttf-font-for-drawstring-image-rendering

Comment: this fix the problem i edit the code to be:
 g.DrawString("the lazy fox...", myCustomFont, RedBrush, 0, 100)

Comment: glad you fixed - sorry my answers couldnt help!

Comment: Your second answer was helpful.
and for a long time I was looking for an answer,
I am new to the stackoverflow and i dont know how to set your answer as the most helpfull.